# transitive map on unit interval is onto

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, mixing

I have such a problem:

Prove that if $T : [0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ ($T$ is continuous) is transitive (there exists $x\in X$ which has a dense orbit), then $T$ is onto, and the image of every non-degenerate subinterval of $[0,1]$ is a non-degenrate subinterval of $[0,1]$.

My problem, except the solution, is that I can't imagine this case (esspecially "onto"assumption about one dense orbit seems too weakly for me).

Comment: This is not enough indeed: pick a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0;1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, define $T(f(n)):=f(n+1)$ and $T(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrationnal. Then the orbit of $0$ is dense but $T$ takes only rationnal values.

Comment: Is $T$ measure preserving?

Comment: By a dynamical system I consider a pair consisting of a compact metric space and a continuous transformation of this space.

Comment: Well then what can you say of the range of $T$?

Comment: Continuous image of compact set is compact.

Comment: I'm happy to know what you mean by "dynamical system", but there is no mention of "dynamical system" in the statement of your question. It would be much better if you edited into the body of your question the hypothesis that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: Anyway, if $T$ is contiuous, and it takes on values $x$ and $y$, then it takes on every value between $x$ and $y$, so if its image is dense, then its image is at least the open interval $(0,1)$. But you know the image is compact, so....

Comment: And you know that orbits are subsets of the range, from which fact you can deduce that $[0;1] \subset T([0;1])$. The comment of Gerry Myerson, specifically the use of the IVT, will help you for the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the second question:

We assume, that for some interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset [0,1]$ with $\alpha<\beta$, $T([\alpha,\beta])$ is a point, say $T([\alpha,\beta])=A$ for $ A\in[0,1]$. Then there exist $x_{1},x_{2}$ such that $\alpha<x_{1}<x_{2}<\beta$ and $x_{1},x_{2}\in T^{-1}(A)$. $T$ is transitive, so there exists $x_{0}$ such that for some $m_{1},m_{2}\in\mathbb{N} \ \ \ T^{m_{1}}(x_{0})$ is arbitrarly close to $x_{1}$ and $T^{m_{2}}(x_{0})$ is arbitrarly close to $x_{2}$. Hence $T(T^{m_{1}}(x_{0})=A=T(T^{m_{2}}(x_{0})) \iff  T^{m_{1}+1}(x_{0})=T^{m_{2}+1}(x_{0})$. WLOG assume $m_{1}>m_{2}$ and then $T^{m_{1}-m_{2}}(x_{0})=x_{0}$, so $x_0$ is a fixed point and we have a contradiction.